# how to store AWS credentials in serverless yml file?

Tags: environment-variables, serverless, aws-credentials

i want to use the AWS credentials in the code to connect to mongodb

```
const user = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  const pass = encodeURIComponent(
    process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  )
```

but i get `undefined`. my serverless credentials are configured.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the environment in your serverless.yml file.
Here is an example->

```
provider:
    environment:
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'asdasda123123XXX'
```

Now you can access it in your code as process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY